# How to access Oracle VM virtualmachine's database from local computer in Visual Studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, virtual-machine

I created database on Oracle VM virtualmachine and I need to use it from my local computer for my project, which I develop on Visual studio. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to VS,
you need to make sure the network device you installed is reachable from the outer world, and that there is a route from your machine to the VM ip device.
What I write here is the simplest configuration in the case you have a home network...
withing Oracle virtualBox -> choose the VM ->(right click) Settings -> Network.
choose "Bridged Adapter" and select the physical card on your computer.
within the VM make sure the IP address is being taken from DHCP (How to do it depends on the Linux distribution you have).
After doing so - restart the network device within the VM, and make sure both of the machines, the windows and the linux, have the same IP segment, and that ping from the windows can reach the linux VM with Oracle.

If you do not have a home network - 
The VM added another networking device on your windows machine (if it is hosted on the same machine), which you need to route the trafic to the VM IP to.

If it is not on the same machine - you need to make sure that the router both the machines are connected to knows about the path to the database.

After the networking issue was resolved (and you can practically ping from one machine to the other assuming the firewall allows it), 
make sure the listener on the DB machine listens to the right address.
this link will help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm

Than you should be done.

Let me know if this wasn't the problem, and your issue is configuring VS - since this is a different issue, which will depend on if your using ODAC or ODT...

Also let me know if you don't know how to check/configure any of the things I wrote above - I didn't write it all since it is long and complicated to answwer all of it in one post...

Comment: Hey, to tell the truth it's as you said and I don't know how to do check/configure any of the things you wrote above

Comment: Which VM software and version do you have? do you host it on the same machine as VS? can you check the IP of the VM (ifconfig) and the IP of the windows machine (ipconfig) and post both ? (don't post it if it's an internet IP, only if it's internal network)

Comment: Oracle VM VirtualBox mannager (OTN developer day VM), I host it in same machine. I cheked both IP but don't know which is needed (pretty green in this area)

Comment: Are the IP's on the same segment? (192.168... )

Comment: So try what I wrote, above - make sure you have both IP's on the same segment, and that you can ping from the windows to the linux (the reason I chose this approach for you is that it requires the least windows and linux networking configurations). Make sure the listener listens on the right address, and you're good to go. I would also recommend to login to the router and reserve the linux DHCP address, so you won't have to update the IP address in the listener and client everytime.